How to build linux, macOS and windows electron desktop app using GitLab Pipelines
How can I build linux, macOs and windows Desktop apps with electron. I have the following pipeline:
image: node:14

stages:
  - build

variables:
  ELECTRON_CACHE: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/electron"
  ELECTRON_BUILDER_CACHE: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/electron-builder"

before_script:
  - npm install -g electron-builder
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y wine
build_macos:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build:mac
    - electron-builder --mac --x64
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/*.dmg
      - dist/*.zip
  only:
    - main

build_windows:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
    - npm install
    - apt-get install wine
    - npm run build:win
    - electron-builder --win --x64
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/*.exe
      - dist/*.zip
  only:
    - main

build_linux:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build:linux
    - electron-builder --linux --x64
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/*.AppImage
      - dist/*.deb
      - dist/*.rpm
  only:
    - main

but I get the following error while building windows:
npm run build:win

> jg-desktop@1.0.3 build:win /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app
> electron-builder --win
> • electron-builder  version=24.13.3 os=5.15.154+
> • artifacts will be published if draft release exists  reason=CI detected
> • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
> • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=31.3.0 appOutDir=dist/win-unpacked
> • downloading     url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v31.3.0/electron-v31.3.0-win32-x64.zip size=111 MB parts=4
> • downloaded      url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v31.3.0/electron-v31.3.0-win32-x64.zip duration=3.075s
> • downloading     url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z size=5.6 MB parts=1
> • downloaded      url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z duration=426ms
> ⨯ wine is required, please see https://electron.build/multi-platform-build#linux  
> ⨯ /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
> Exit code:
> 1  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
> Exit code:
> 1
> at ChildProcess.\<anonymous\> (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:252:14)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
> From previous event:
> at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)
> From previous event:
> at WinPackager.signApp (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/winPackager.ts:384:27)
> at WinPackager.doSignAfterPack (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:336:32)
> at WinPackager.doPack (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:321:7)
> at WinPackager.pack (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:140:5)
> at Packager.doBuild (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:445:9)
> at executeFinally (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/builder-util/src/promise.ts:12:14)
> at Packager.\_build (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:379:31)
> at Packager.build (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:340:12)
> at executeFinally (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/builder-util/src/promise.ts:12:14)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! jg-desktop@1.0.3 build:win: `electron-builder --win`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the jg-desktop@1.0.3 build:win script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/\_logs/2024-07-31T06_44_43_537Z-debug.log
> Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1\`

and for macOS:
$ npm run build:mac
> jg-desktop@1.0.3 build:mac /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app
> electron-builder --mac
  • electron-builder  version=24.13.3 os=5.15.154+
  • artifacts will be published if draft release exists  reason=CI detected
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  ⨯ Cannot find module 'dmg-license'
Require stack:
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmgLicense.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmg.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmgUtil.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/macPackager.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/electron-builder/out/builder.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/electron-builder/out/cli/cli.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/electron-builder/cli.js  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Cannot find module 'dmg-license'
Require stack:
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmgLicense.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmg.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmgUtil.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/macPackager.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/electron-builder/out/builder.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/electron-builder/out/cli/cli.js
- /builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/electron-builder/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/dmg-builder/src/dmgLicense.ts:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/repo/jg-desktop-app/node_modules/dmg-builder/src/dmg.ts:13:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jg-desktop@1.0.3 build:mac: `electron-builder --mac`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jg-desktop@1.0.3 build:mac script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-31T06_44_37_599Z-debug.log
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I want to create an Elektron desktop application for Linux, macOS and Windows. The Linux build package works fine. Can anyone help me?

Have you seen the errors in your log? It seems like for windows you need wine installed and for macOS the module dmg-license could not be found. Have you tried to execute the commands on windows and macOS by hand?

I don't have a macOS machine. I'm installing the wine package in the build_windows function. Is there any other way to manage this with Gitlap Pipelines

It would suprise me if it would be possible to build the macOS app without mac hardware. The documentation also only contains a section abput building windows app from linux. Regarding your windows build: have you tried using the recomended docker image electronuserland/builder:wine?
